# How to start and stop jboss server using Ant task?

Tags: ant, jboss

I need to stop, deploy my ear file and start Jboss server using the Ant tasks.

I am able to compile, build and deploy my J2EE application as an ear file into the JBoss server successfully using Ant tasks. We can see the redeployment of my application in the jboss console. I want to stop the server before deployment and start the server.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

Here how you start/stop JBoss app container including deploy an application :

```
<!-- Stop Jboss -->
<target name="stop-jboss" description="Stops back-end EJB container" >
    <exec executable="${jboss.bin.dir}/shutdown.bat" spawn="true">
        <arg line="-S" />
    </exec>
    <echo>+-----------------------------+</echo>
    <echo>| J B O S S   S T O P P E D   |</echo>
    <echo>+-----------------------------+</echo>
</target>

<!-- Start Jboss -->
<target name="start-jboss" description="Starts back-end EJB container" >
    <exec executable="${jboss.bin.dir}/run.bat" spawn="true">
    </exec>
    <echo>+-----------------------------+</echo>
    <echo>| J B O S S   S T A R T E D   |</echo>
    <echo>+-----------------------------+</echo>
</target>

<!-- deploy target-->
<target name="deploy-war" description="deploy war file" depends="prepare">
  <sequential>
    <antcall target="stop-jboss" />
    <war destfile="${file.name}" webxml="conf/web.xml">
       <classes dir="bin" />
    </war>
    <antcall target="start-jboss" />
        <echo>+----------------------------+</echo>
        <echo>|   W A R  D E P L O Y E D   |</echo>
        <echo>+----------------------------+</echo>
  </sequential>
</target>
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Ok, but how can you do this when the JBOSS server is remote?

Answer (score 0):

[Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) supports ANT and is designed to support several J2EE containers

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate os independent answer would be something like this:

```
<property name="my.jboss.home" value="/path/to/jboss/install/dir" />
<property name="my.jboss.host" value="localhost" />
<property name="my.jboss.port" value="9999" />
<property name="my.jboss.name" value="my-jboss-instance" />
<property name="my.jboss.debugport" value="8787" />

<!-- supposedly this is built by a seperate task -->
<property name="my.deployment" value="${basedir}/build/deployment.ear" />

<!-- starting preset -->
<presetdef name="start-jboss-preset">
    <java jar="${jboss.home}/jboss-modules.jar" fork="true" taskname="${jboss.name}">
        <jvmarg value="-server" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xms1024m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=${jboss.home}/standalone/log/server.log" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dlogging.configuration=file:${jboss.home}/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" />
        <arg line="-mp ${jboss.home}/modules/ -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djboss.home.dir=${jboss.home}" />
        <arg value="-b=localhost" />
        <arg value="-c=standalone-full.xml" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djboss.node.name=${jboss.name}" />
    </java>
</presetdef>

<!-- internal task to actually start jboss -->
<target name="start-jboss">
    <start-jboss-preset />
</target>

<!-- internal task to start jboss in debug mode -->
<target name="start-jboss-debug">
    <start-jboss-preset taskname="dbg:${jboss.name}:${jboss.debugport}">
        <jvmarg value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=${jboss.debugport},server=y,suspend=n" />
    </start-jboss-preset>
</target>

<!-- preset to run jboss-cli, this can be used to push any command to a running
     jboss instance -->
<presetdef name="jboss-cli">
    <java jar="${jboss.home}/jboss-modules.jar" fork="true">
        <arg line="-mp ${jboss.home}/modules org.jboss.as.cli" />
        <arg value="--controller=${jboss.host}:${jboss.port}" />
        <arg value="--connect" />
    </java>
</presetdef>

<!-- the actual shut down command -->
<target name="exec-jboss">
    <jboss-cli failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${jboss.command}" />
    </jboss-cli>
</target>

<!-- public targets with your properties set -->
<target name="start" description="starts jboss instance">
    <antcall target="start-jboss">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${my.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.name" value="${my.jboss.name}" />
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="debug" description="starts jboss instance in debugmode">
    <antcall target="start-jboss-debug">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${my.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.name" value="${my.jboss.name}" />
        <param name="jboss.debugport" value="${my.jboss.debugport}" />
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="stop" description="stops jboss instance">
    <antcall target="exec-jboss">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${my.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.host" value="${my.jboss.host}" />
        <param name="jboss.port" value="${my.jboss.port}" />
        <param name="jboss.command" value="shutdown" />
    </antcall>
</target>

<!-- a dependent build / package task should be present -->
<target name="deploy" description="deploys to a running jboss instance">
    <antcall target="exec-jboss">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${my.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.host" value="${my.jboss.host}" />
        <param name="jboss.port" value="${my.jboss.port}" />
        <param name="jboss.command" value="deploy ${my.deployment}" />
    </antcall>
</target>
```