# How to start stop JBoss server using Ant target?

Tags: xml, ant, jboss

Starting stopping JBoss server using Ant target instead of exec and 
pass the run script i.e.

### build.xml

```
<target="start-jboss" description="Starts JBoss instance" depends="prepare">
    <exec dir="${jboss.home}/bin" executable="cmd.exe" os="Windows07"> 
        <arg line="/c run.bat -S"/> 
        <env key="NOPAUSE" value="true"/> 
    </exec> 
</target>
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060048/how-to-start-and-stop-jboss-server-using-ant-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+7.1.x).

There is also a way to stop JBoss via [JMX Console](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ShutDownJBossWithTheJMXConsole) or even pure JMX (requires custom ant task adapter).

Comment: Am after code implementation approach written in Ant xml script; not through any pro-filer i.e. JConsole, dtrace, yourkit etc. I would like to write an application to automate our code deployment process completely.

Comment: Hi Vadzim, can you give me an overview on how Cargo works interms of starting/stopping tomcat/jboss both locally and remotely. Cheers!

Comment: See https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/cargo/core/trunk/containers/jboss/src/main/java/org/codehaus/cargo/container/jboss/JBoss7xInstalledLocalContainer.java?r=3250. It seems to be using JBoss CLI (at least for local container).