# How to Stop and Restart JBoss 7.1 Application Server With Ant script?

Tags: ant, jboss7.x

I have a JSF project that supported with primefaces. I want to use ant script for complie and deployment operations. I created following build.xml. This Ant script is compiling and deploying project to jboss 7.1. But I could not create ant target for jboss stop and restart operation. I googled and found a ant task for old jboss version int this link:

[How to start and stop jboss server using Ant task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060048/how-to-start-and-stop-jboss-server-using-ant-task)

but Jboss 7.1 does not have "shutdown.bat" and "restart.bat" anymore.

Is there anyone who have experiences with this problem?

Thanks.

Build.xml:

```
<project default="run" basedir="." name="portal">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="JBOSS_HOME" value="C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final"/>
<property name="JBoos.deployment.dir" value="${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/deployments"/>
<property name="JBoos.bin" value="${JBOSS_HOME}/bin"/>
<property name="base" value="."/>
<property name="source" value="${base}/src"/>

<target name="run" depends="clean, compile">
    <war warfile="portal.war" needxmlfile = "false" >
        <fileset dir="${source}/main/webapp"/>
        <classes dir="D:/portalAnt/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <lib file = "C:/MavenRepo/.m2/repository/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.5/primefaces-3.5.jar"/>
        <metainf dir="D:/Personel/Dropbox/Java/primeFaces_WS/portal/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF"/>
    </war>
        <antcall target="deployTarget"/>
        <antcall target="startJboss"/>
</target>

<target name="deployTarget">
    <copy file="${base}/portal.war" todir="${JBoos.deployment.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="startJboss">
    <exec executable="${JBoos.bin}/standalone.bat"/>
</target>

<target name="stopJboss">

</target>   

<path id="MavenLib">
     <!-- Maven libs are here. -->
</path>

<path id="JbossLib">
   <!-- Jboss libs are here. -->
</path>

<path id="portal.classpath">
    <path refid="MavenLib"/>
    <path refid="JBossLib"/>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="D:/portalAnt/WEB-INF/classes">
        <classpath refid="portal.classpath"/>
    </javac>
    <mkdir dir="D:/portalAnt/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF"/>
    <copy file="${base}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml" todir="D:/portalAnt/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF"/> 
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete file ="${JBoos.deployment.dir}/portal.war"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using jboss-cli.bat.

```
> bin\jboss-cli.bat --connect --command=:shutdown
```

You need to add target ip as parameter for `--connect`, if it is not localhost.

For restart (actually reload)

```
> bin\jboss-cli.bat --connect --command=:reload
```

From comment by GreenGiant, for a full restart:

```
> bin\jboss-cli.bat --connect --command=:shutdown(restart=true)
```

Comment: For a full restart, use `--command=:shutdown(restart=true)`. See [this link](http://developer-should-know.tumblr.com/post/134998277567/what-is-event-driven-architecture-why-do-we-need)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. Ant Script target should be like this:

```
<target name="stopJboss">
    <exec executable="${JBoos.bin}/jboss-cli.bat">
        <arg value="--connect" />
        <arg value="--command=:shutdown" />
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="reloadJboss">
    <exec executable="${JBoos.bin}/jboss-cli.bat">
        <arg value="--connect" />
        <arg value="--command=:reload" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here:

[How to start and stop jboss server using Ant task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060048/how-to-start-and-stop-jboss-server-using-ant-task/33777483#33777483)

The appropriate os independent answer would be something like this:

```
<property name="my.jboss.home" value="/path/to/jboss/install/dir" />
<property name="my.jboss.host" value="localhost" />
<property name="my.jboss.port" value="9999" />
<property name="my.jboss.name" value="my-jboss-instance" />
<property name="my.jboss.debugport" value="8787" />

<!-- supposedly this is built by a seperate task -->
<property name="my.deployment" value="${basedir}/build/deployment.ear" />

<!-- starting preset -->
<presetdef name="start-jboss-preset">
    <java jar="${jboss.home}/jboss-modules.jar" fork="true" taskname="${jboss.name}">
        <jvmarg value="-server" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xms1024m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=${jboss.home}/standalone/log/server.log" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dlogging.configuration=file:${jboss.home}/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" />
        <arg line="-mp ${jboss.home}/modules/ -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djboss.home.dir=${jboss.home}" />
        <arg value="-b=localhost" />
        <arg value="-c=standalone-full.xml" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djboss.node.name=${jboss.name}" />
    </java>
</presetdef>

<!-- internal task to actually start jboss -->
<target name="start-jboss">
    <start-jboss-preset />
</target>

<!-- internal task to start jboss in debug mode -->
<target name="start-jboss-debug">
    <start-jboss-preset taskname="dbg:${jboss.name}:${jboss.debugport}">
        <jvmarg value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=${jboss.debugport},server=y,suspend=n" />
    </start-jboss-preset>
</target>

<!-- preset to run jboss-cli, this can be used to push any command to a running
     jboss instance -->
<presetdef name="jboss-cli">
    <java jar="${jboss.home}/jboss-modules.jar" fork="true">
        <arg line="-mp ${jboss.home}/modules org.jboss.as.cli" />
        <arg value="--controller=${jboss.host}:${jboss.port}" />
        <arg value="--connect" />
    </java>
</presetdef>

<!-- the actual shut down command -->
<target name="exec-jboss">
    <jboss-cli failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${jboss.command}" />
    </jboss-cli>
</target>

<!-- public targets with your properties set -->
<target name="start" description="starts jboss instance">
    <antcall target="start-jboss">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${my.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.name" value="${my.jboss.name}" />
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="debug" description="starts jboss instance in debugmode">
    <antcall target="start-jboss-debug">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${my.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.name" value="${my.jboss.name}" />
        <param name="jboss.debugport" value="${my.jboss.debugport}" />
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="stop" description="stops jboss instance">
    <antcall target="exec-jboss">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${my.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.host" value="${my.jboss.host}" />
        <param name="jboss.port" value="${my.jboss.port}" />
        <param name="jboss.command" value="shutdown" />
    </antcall>
</target>

<!-- a dependent build / package task should be present -->
<target name="deploy" description="deploys to a running jboss instance">
    <antcall target="exec-jboss">
        <param name="jboss.home" value="${my.jboss.home}" />
        <param name="jboss.host" value="${my.jboss.host}" />
        <param name="jboss.port" value="${my.jboss.port}" />
        <param name="jboss.command" value="deploy ${my.deployment}" />
    </antcall>
</target>
```